# Alfresco Lucene and CMIS

Tags: lucene, alfresco, cmis

We have this problem:

yesterday we had custom xmlModel in Alfresco that had a custom type, extension of content with a property and some mandatory aspects.

```
<type name="custom:myType">
     <title>Object</title>
     <parent>cm:content</parent>
     <properties>
        <property name="custom:myProperty">
           <type>d:text</type>
        </property>
     </properties>
     <mandatory-aspects>
        <aspect>custom:myAspect1</aspect>
     </mandatory-aspects>
  </type>
```

now we have the urgent need to move the custom my Property  to a new aspect like this:

```
 <aspect name="custom:myAspect2">
     <title>new aspect</title>
     <properties>
        <property name="custom:myProperty">
           <type>d:text</type>
           <mandatory enforced='true'>true</mandatory>
        </property>
     </properties>
  </aspect>
```

and the type is now:

```
<type name="custom:myType">
 <title>Object</title>
 <parent>cm:content</parent>
 <mandatory-aspects>
    <aspect>custom:myAspect1</aspect>
    <aspect>custom:myAspect2</aspect>
 </mandatory-aspects>
```

After a full rebuild index, Lucene seems not to be considering these changes.
So in Alfresco on new documents everythings fine, on the old ones, uplodaded with the old model and now reindexed, we have still the property, but missing the aspect.
Is that normal behaviour? or some issue/bug.
All of this is caused by our need to make CMIS queries on aspects, but we have some problems making queries on a native property of a type that is not part of an aspect in Alfresco. It seems only being possible to extract properties of an aspect and not of a content type. Is that true?
thanks

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first part of your problem, you may need to run a script to add the aspect to the old objects. I'm actually surprised the repo was able to start because those old objects should be complaining that their type requires a mandatory aspect that hasn't been added to the object.

If I were making the change you made, I would have declared the aspect first as an empty aspect, then run a script to add the aspect to all of the nodes where it makes sense, then update the model to move the property from the type to the aspect and restart.

Regarding your second question about CMIS and queries, you should be able to query properties defined as part of a type through CMIS with no problem whatsoever. The problem is when your properties move to aspects. Then your queries have to do a join like this:

```
queryString = "select d.*, w.* from cmis:document as d join sc:webable as w on d.cmis:objectId = w.cmis:objectId where w.sc:isActive = True";
```

In this example, sc:webable is an aspect and the sc:isActive property is defined on that aspect.

So if you said you were having trouble querying properties defined on aspects, that would make more sense (because of the join requirement) than having trouble querying properties defined on types.

Also, note that adding and removing aspects to/from objects, asking an object if it has an aspect, and setting or updating properties defined on an aspect all require you to use an extension because aspects are not supported by CMIS 1.0 out-of-the-box. There is an [extension for OpenCMIS](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/alfresco-opencmis-extension/) and another [extension for cmislib](http://code.google.com/p/cmislib-alfresco-extension/).

Comment: For the first part, the old objects aren't missing the old mandatory property, cause now the old property is in the mandatory aspect. It should work the same. We have also 7mil files and running a script is not an option. For the second part, we are making joins without problems, (oh we are using a webscript for CMIS to make joins and get aspects and their properties of nodes). The problem is that in the xml returned by CMIS, there aren't any type properties inside only aspect ones, so when we parse the xml and populate a table for viewing results, we can't import type properties as values.

Comment: Based on the type you show above you should only have type properties from cm:content because that's the type's parents and there are no other properties defined. The rest will show up as part of the aspect.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't posted the entire piece of xml. Our type has one property, and more aspects with a set of properties. When we execute the query via CMIS we make a JOIN as you said, and it works on aspect properties, but we don't know how to get that single property in the type tag (not the one in aspects). Beside, we manages to treat that property as aspect so we created an alias and JOIN that property with all the others. This workaround works, but we're not sure if it's the right way. Hope I was clear about the problem..